# Is there a way in Google Sheets to create a hyperlink in a cell pointing to a local file in my PC?

Tags: windows, google-sheets, hyperlink

For some time now I have been working in Sheets with links to Google Drive files.

However, I would like to know whether there is a simialr approach with files located in a specific windows folder located in my local machine, something such as d:\downloads\file-1.pdf.

The idea is that, by clicking the hyperlink, the associated program that opens that extension pops up and opens the file.

Comment: Related: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler

Comment: Do you only want the string of the file path in your PC pasted in the Sheet or do you need it to do something else? I think a scenario of what you want to accomplish would be better to understand your use case.

Comment: Thanks Fernando. The link should work in the same as it does with Google Drive links or other http based links. With http links a new tab in your internet browser opens up. With local files in your PC the associated software that opens that extensions (pfd, jpb etc) should open., same as it happens when you browse and run in Windows explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Google Docs and Sheets allow only `http` protocols to point to links.
Never to local files or folders.
However, there is a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25565613/add-link-to-open-a-local-file-in-google-docs).

Comment: You should close your question by duplicated